Automatically turning a cutout section into a manifold object without using solidify modifier or third party plugins?
The object below was cut out of the surface of another object. I want to turn it into a manifold object where the lines marked in red are filled in with faces without having to manually extrude\fill them individually?
The aim is to make these four planes into a box section with an angle in the center.

I'm pretty sure that I've seen this done with a couple of keypresses using only the base version of blender, without any third party plugins, and without using the solidify modifier. The person giving the demonstration selected either the edges or the vertex and  then filled in the rest automatically.

They may have used the (built-in but not enabled by default) F2 addon? See the Blender manual for details. See also this YT video. It's quite old but still relavent.
